# Libcurl and curl_global_init in shared library loaded at runtime

Tags: c, thread-safety, libcurl, glib

I am developing a photo booth application that uses 3 modules to provide printing, capturing, and triggering functionality. The idea is that people can develop modules for it that extend this functionality. These modules are implemented as shared libraries that are loaded at runtime when the user clicks "start".

I am trying to implement a printer module that "prints" to a facebook image gallery. I want to use libcurl for this. My problem is with the initialization function: `curl_global_init()` The libcurl API documentation states that this function is absolutely not thread safe. From [the docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html):

> **This function is not thread safe.** You must not call it when any other thread in the program (i.e. a thread sharing the same memory) is running. This doesn't just mean no other thread that is using libcurl. Because curl_global_init() calls functions of other libraries that are similarly thread unsafe, it could conflict with any other thread that uses these other libraries.

[Elsewhere](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html) in the documentation it says:

> The global constant situation merits special consideration when the code you are writing to use libcurl is not the main program, but rather a modular piece of a program, e.g. another library. As a module, your code doesn't know about other parts of the program -- it doesn't know whether they use libcurl or not. And its code doesn't necessarily run at the start and end of the whole program.
>
> A module like this must have global constant functions of its own, just like curl_global_init() and curl_global_cleanup(). The module thus has control at the beginning and end of the program and has a place to call the libcurl functions.

...which seems to address the issue. However, this seems to imply that my module's `init()` and `finalize()` functions would be called at the program's beginning and end. Since the modules are designed to be swappable at runtime, there is no way I can do this. Even if I could, my application uses GLib, which per their [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-Threads.html), it is never safe to assume there are no threads running:

> ...Since version 2.32, the GLib threading system is automatically initialized at the start of your program, and all thread-creation functions and synchronization primitives are available right away.
>
> Note that it is not safe to assume that your program has no threads even if you don't call g_thread_new() yourself. GLib and GIO can and will create threads for their own purposes...

My question is: is there any way to safely call `curl_global_init()` in my application? Can I put the calls to `curl_global_init()` and `curl_global_cleanup()` in my module's `init()` and `finalize()` functions? Do I need to find another HTTP library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you won't really find any other library without these restrictions since they are inherited by libcurl from 3rd party (SSL mostly) libraries with those restrictions. For example OpenSSL.

This said, the thread safe situation for global_init is very unfortunate and something we (in the curl project) really strongly dislike but cannot do much about as long as we use those other libraries. This also means that the *exact* situation for you depends on exactly which dependency libraries your libcurl is built to use.

You will in most situations be perfectly fine with calling curl_global_init() from your modules init() function the way you suggest. I can't guarantee this to be safe with 100% certainty of course since there are a few unknowns here that I cannot speak to.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I had been considering forking a process from my module, and having the child process handle the real work for other reasons, but I decided against it in favor of a simpler solution. However, it seems to me that this might be the safest way to work around this issue.

Comment: @Chris Beware that if you fork() in a multithreaded program, you must not call any async-signal-unsafe functions (that is, almost anything) before a successful execve(). You would need to create a separate exectuable.